# Why my anchor have different style with my submit button?

Tags: html, css

I created a submit button and anchor link with same class name, with same style. But the result is different. My anchor link is bigger than my submit button. Like this

[image]

**Here's the snippet**

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 13px 30px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 blue;
    
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn">
<a href="" class="btn">Login</a>
```

How to make it have same size? without set the height to exactly px or set the line height of the element. Thanks in advance

*on the jsfiddle or sippet have same style, but when I create and run on local browser it's say different thing*

Comment: try to add `line-height: 1em;`

Comment: There's actually a difference between them in the jsfiddle as well. The anchor's content is 1px taller than the button content. borders, paddings and margins are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a `line-height` in the `.btn` class makes them equally tall.

```css
.btn {
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 13px 30px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 blue;
    
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn">
<a href="" class="btn">Login</a>
```